# jQuery Function Does Not Fire if Gravity Form Entry Fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gravityforms

I am using jQuery to add a "disabled" attribute to my submit button once it is clicked.

```
        $('#submit-button').click(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#submit-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
            }, 50);
        })
```

I am using gravity forms and am using AJAX to produce a spinner image when it's clicked, that's why I have the setTimeout function.

This works the first time the submit button is clicked. If the entry passes validation then it's no problem, the disabled attribute is loaded and then goes to the confirmation page.

The issue is when the validation fails, the page refreshes and shows the errors (e.g. this was not filled out correctly) and then click the submit button does not fire the jQuery click function to add the disabled attribute

Comment: Hard to troubleshoot this with just the snippet you provided.

Comment: Possibly an event delegation issue, or possibly due to the lack of `preventDefault()` being called if the `#submit-button` submits a form as its name implies. We can't help you without seeing all relevant code. The timeout itself seems a little redundant, though.

Comment: use `function(ev) {` and than as your first function body line: `ev.preventDefault();` - And remove that setTimeout - it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gravity forms gform_page_loaded works - https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_page_loaded/

I put the code in a function and used

```
jQuery(document).on('gform_page_loaded', function(event, form_id, current_page){
        myFunction()
    });
```

So now the function runs after the AJAX call